# I want to Build a Chart , The script can be used to extract the table dependency graph either from the parameter file in the CSV format (.csv/.param)

Tags: python

File1: Headers are  Tablename, Fieldname , From, To , Group

And the values are
Tablename;Fieldname;From;To;Group
BKPF;MANDT;;;cdbbb199
ACDOCA;XSETTLED;;;5ea87117   and many more

I want to prepare a chart on the basis of this values and Create a graph

I tried PYvis but it won't work out

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! At the moment, the given information is not sufficient to produce a meaningful chart (in particular, no numerical value can be found in your data). Would you please edit your question and add more of your dataset? Ideally, additionally add the code you have tried so far, (even though it did not work) so that others can get an idea of which data exactly should be plotted.

Comment: still not enough information for me to create anything useful, unfortunatly :)